# Splitting a number to a sum of perfect powers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, perfect-powers

Given a number $N$, is it possible to determine whether the number can be splitted to a sum of $c$ perfect powers:

> $N={a_1}^q+{a_2}^w+.....{a_c}^t$

Comment: Can the powers be different or do they have to be the same? If same then the general results are any number is sum of 4 squares, 9 cubes, 19 fourth powers etc. This is called the Waring Problem.

Comment: The powers can be different

Comment: Are the $a_i$ non-negative? If so, the exponents are bounded by $\log N / \log 2$, and so there are only finitely many possibilities to check, making it very possible to determine what you ask.

Comment: Trivial even for c = 1 if an exponent of 1 is allowed :-)